# How to loop a random number of times in jax with jit compilation?

Tags: python, random, jit, jax

I am using jax in python, and I want to loop over some code for a random number of times. This is part of a function which is jit compiled later. I have a small example below which should explain what I want to do.

```py
num_iters = jax.random.randint(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), (1,), 1, 10)[0]
arr = []
for i in range(num_iters):
  arr += [i*i]
```

This works without any error and gives `arr=[0,1,4]` at the end of the loop (with the fixed seed of `0` that we're using in `PRNGKey`).

However, if this is part of a jit-compiled function:

```py
@jax.jit
def do_stuff(start):
  num_iters = jax.random.randint(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), (1,), 1, 10)[0]
  arr = []
  for i in range(num_iters):
    arr += [i*i]
  for value in arr:
    start += value
  return start
```

I get a `TracerIntegerConversionError` on `num_iters`. The function works fine without the jit decorator. How to get this to work with jit? I basically just want to construct the list `arr` whose length depends on a random number. Alternatively, I can also use a list with the maximum possible size, but then I'd have to loop over it a random number of times.

---

**Further context**

It's possible to make it not throw an error using a `numpy` random number generator instead:

```py
@jax.jit
def do_stuff(start):
  np_rng = np.random.default_rng()
  num_iters = np_rng.integers(1, 10)
  arr = []
  for i in range(num_iters):
    arr += [i*i]
  for value in arr:
    start += value
  return start
```

However, this is not what I want. There is a jax `rng` which is passed to my function which I wish to use to generate `num_iters`. Otherwise, `arr` always has the same length since the `numpy` seed is fixed to what was available at jit-compile time, and I always get the same result without any randomness. However, if I use that `rng` key as seed for `numpy` (like `np.random.default_rng(seed=rng[0])`) it again gives the following error:

```
TypeError: SeedSequence expects int or sequence of ints for entropy not Traced<ShapedArray(uint32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`jax.lax.fori_loop`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.fori_loop.html) for this:

```py
import jax

@jax.jit
def do_stuff(start):
  num_iters = jax.random.randint(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), (1,), 1, 10)[0]
  return jax.lax.fori_loop(0, num_iters, lambda i, val: val + i * i, start)

print(do_stuff(10))
# 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Jax complains in this case, because you try to use a traced value as a static integer. See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerIntegerConversionError for more information.

As one possible solution you could pass the `num_iters` as an argument to `do_stuff`, declare it as static and create the keys outside, along the lines of:

```py
import jax
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def do_stuff(start, num_iters):    
  arr = []
  
  for i in range(num_iters):
    arr += [i*i]
  
  for value in arr:
    start += value
  
  return start

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(238)

for _ in range(4):
  key, _ = jax.random.split(key)
  num_iters = int(jax.random.randint(key, (1,), 1, 10))
  print(do_stuff(0, num_iters))
```

Which prints:

```
5
0
140
30
```

Other alternative solutions are proposed in the link I listed above.

I hope this helps!